# "expected nested-name-specifier before ‘const’ error" with typename const in g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have this code in C++

```
template<typename T>
class DD
: public enumerables<T>

{
...
private:
    typename const DD<T>& mContainer;
}
```

And it gives me two error messages :

1. error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘const’
2. error: invalid declarator before ‘&’ token

What's wrong with `typename const` code? It compiles fine with MSVC C++.

### ADDED

`typename DD<T>& const mContainer;` and `const typename DD<T>& mContainer;` give me the same error.

Comment: MSVC never learned to use `typename` and `template` within a dependent context correctly. Don't use templates with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, what's that `typename` doing there? You are not referring to a nested type, so `typename` is totally unnecessary there. I'd say that the error is caused by that unjustified use of `typename`, not by ordering of the parts of the declaration or anything else.

It should be just

```
const DD<T>& mContainer;
```

or even

```
const DD& mContainer;
```

Answer (score 4):

Except when introducing a template type parameter, the keyword `typename` must *always* be immediately followed by an optional global-scope `::` token and then a *nested-name-specifier*; that is, something which has one or more namespaces or classes, each followed by the `::` token.

See the syntax rules in the C++ Standard: 5.2 (function-style cast), 7.1.5.3 (elaborated type specifier), and 7.3.3 (using declaration).

Also, 14.6p5: "The keyword `typename` shall be applied only to qualified names, but those names need not be dependent."

Microsoft's compiler is wrong to accept the invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone since I don't see it explicitly mentioned as an answer or comment (though the answers which cite references to the C++ spec allude to it),  if you're getting this error when a dependent type is present.

For example:

```
<template T>
void foo(typename const T::size_type & n);
```

The fix is to move `const` before `typename`:

```
<template T>
void foo(const typename T::size_type & n);
```

Confirmed this works for GCC (4.9) and MSVC (2017).