# Parsing an XML file in C++ using RapidXML with Dev C++

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, tree, dev-c++, rapidxml

So I have to parse an XML file for my C++ project in class and I'm using RapidXML. The rapidxml_iterators.hpp file is giving me some troubles. I'm using Dev C++ by the way

At first, I had the following code:

```
typedef typename xml_node<Ch> value_type;
typedef typename xml_node<Ch> &reference;
typedef typename xml_node<Ch> *pointer;
typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
```

Inside my main.cpp, I did: #include "rapidxml_iterators.hpp" and gave me an expected nested-name specifier error when I tried to compile it. I followed the instructions from [compile rapidxml under linux with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830822/compile-rapidxml-under-linux-with-g) and changed the code from the top to the following:

```
typedef xml_node<Ch> value_type;
typedef xml_node<Ch> &reference;
typedef xml_node<Ch> *pointer;
typedef typename std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef typename std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
```

Now, it's giving me these errors:

-no class template named `ptrdiff_t' in`std' 
-ISO C++ forbids declaration of `difference_type' with no type

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this code, I'd be forever grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The other errors are:
`ISO C++ forbids the declaration of difference_type with no type`

and

`no class template named bidirectional_iterator_tag in std`

and the rest of the errors are just repeated instances of these two but with different things such as `iterator_category`

Answer (score 0):

You lack the definition of `std::ptrdiff_t`. So the compiler tells you that you cannot `typedef` it since it is not defined.

Just include the proper header at the top of your file and you'll be good (with this error only!), that is, add:

```c
#include <cstddef>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply! Now I'm not getting the std::ptrdiff_t error anymore but it still gives me these issues:

`ISO C++ forbids the declaration of difference_type with no type`

and

`no class template named bidirectional_iterator_tag in std`

and the rest of the errors are just repeated instances of these two

Comment: Ok cool. Then please mark this as an answer so that this issue is closed, and open a new topic with your new problems if you feel like it.

Comment: Actually, no it still gives me the `std::ptrdiff_t` error still. Wow

Comment: any other suggestions? I'm clueless. Is it because of Dev C++?

Comment: look for your `cstddef` header on your system and look what's inside. Does it define `std::ptrdiff_t`? Maybe you need to turn a flag on? Post your header on a pastebin and post it as an update to your initial post.

Comment: Where would I be able to check the header?

Comment: depends on your system, check for the place of the standard header, or just do a filename search on the header you want.